# Can't get overwrite to work during File.Copy - unable to access error

Tags: c#, file-io

I have been looking all at kinds of solutions for allowing an overwrite to occur from the following error

> {"The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\pathway\filename.txt' because it is being
>   used by another process."}

I have tried, `flushing`, `closing`, `GC.Collect()`, ect... but I cannot seem to find a way pass this error.

I write a "temp" file as such

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                foreach (var line in detailLines)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        GC.Collect();
```

Then allow the user to specify their own destination where I copy the file above, to.

```
private void SaveFile()
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFile.FileName = fileName;
    saveFile.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";            
    if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, saveFile.FileName, true);
    }
}
```

I can save as a new name fine, but if I attempt to save at the same pathway and name as the "temp" file, then it asks "if I want to replace this file" and after I click yes it crashes and throws that cannot access error.

Can someone explain how I can access and overwrite a file in the same destination?

Comment: Hmm... what do you expect to happen if you try to copy the file onto itself?

Comment: Well I understand that..and see why it is complaining, but is there some sort of IO tool that will temp make that file in the background and then let me use that as my copy? Or do I need to make a physical "temp" file to copy from?

Comment: Hold on for a second. Copying a file onto itself does not make any sense, not even from a rational or logical standpoint... what do you really want?

Comment: No, sorry. What I mean is. I understand that I am trying to copy to the file I am copying from..it breaks. What I am wondering is what is the simplest way to accomplish a copy and overrwrite on the same file. Is there some file IO option that will make a hidden temp (thus two files) then overwrite the physical file with the hidden one). Otherwise I guess I will have to save my "temp" file as a physical file somewhere, save the user's destination file, copy, then delete the temp file. I am looking for something less exhausting.

Comment: The `true` parameter passed to the *Copy* method tells the system to overwrite the target file if it already exists (and if permissions allow it, of course). Why exactly do you want to create and/or make a copy of the temp file first instead of writing the data directly to the user's destination file...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx) method says that:

> Overwriting a file of the same name is allowed.

It actually fails to succeed in it(looks like something else has been meant by this sentence):

```
try
{
    String filePath = @"C:\TEMP\test.txt";
    using (var fs = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        fs.Write("data");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("File written");

    // Fails
    System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, filePath, true);

    Console.WriteLine("File overwritten by itself");

}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

**So**, you should probably just check whether the temp file and target file are the same and act accordingly:

```
if (fileName != saveFile.FileName)
    System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, saveFile.FileName, true);
```

**P.S.:** There is always some probability of race conditions in the file system, but I don't think that you should really worry about it - dealing with it will just make your code more complex and improve nothing.